# Classic ASP or ASP.NET : make multiple async calls, return when all complete

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, asynchronous

I need to gather information (via GET) from several other websites (not under my control), do some processing (specific to each source) on the data returned, and then print all the info out to the user.

Right now I'm making the GET request to website A, waiting for it to return, processing it, then calling website B, and so on... Obviously this is too damn slow. I'd like to make async requests to A, B, and C, then process each response as it comes back, and once I have all the responses, print it all out to the user.

I'm allowed to use classic asp or vb.net. I'm more familiar with classic asp but I'm willing to learn...

Answer (score 0):

.NET will allow you to create threads and have each thread process independently.  I was on classic for a long time (skeptical of .NET) but really, it's far FAR superior.

Answer (score 0):

It would help if you posted some code to start with but...

Look at [ThreadStart](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadstart.aspx), it has simple, short example to get you started if you don't have any idea where to start